# What is the mistake that i am doing in my pig latin translator

Tags: python, typeerror

1. if a word begins with a vowel the word 'yay' is added at the end of the word.
2. if the word begin with a cosonant or consonant cluster, that consonant or consonant cluster is moved to the end the word followed by 'ay'.

   ```
    def vowel(value):
        value=str(value)
        vowels=['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']
        if value[0]in vowels:
        value=value+'yay'
        return(value)
    def consonant(value):
        value=str(value)
        vowels=['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']
        b=0
        for i in range(len(value)):
        if a[i] in vowels:
           b=i
           break
        c=a[b:len(a)]+a[0:b]+'ay'
        return(c)
    spam='My name is AL SWEIGART and i am 4000 years old.'
    spam1=spam.split()
    a=['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']
    for i in range(len(spam1)):
        if spam1[i][0] in a:
           spam1.insert(vowels(spam1[i]),i)
        else:
           spam1.insert(consonant(spam1[i]),i)
    print(spam1)
   ```
3. TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
    in 
   22         spam1.insert(vowels(spam1[i]),i)
   23     else:
   ---> 24         spam1.insert(consonant(spam1[i]),i)
   25 print(spam1)

   in consonant(value)
   13             b=i
   14             break
   ---> 15     c=a[b:len(a)]+a[0:b]+'ay'
   16     return(c)
   17 spam='My name is AL SWEIGART and i am 4000 years old.'

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: Can you repost with your code properly formatted

Answer (score 0):

First thing first it seems that you mixed up `value` with `a` in the `consonant()` function, and since you refer to `a[b:len(a)]` when declaring `c`, it seems that Python refers to the `a` variable which happens to be a list instead of string (`['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']`)

In this specific line of code,

```py
c=a[b:len(a)]+a[0:b]+'ay'
```

`c` is declared as a **list** instead of string containing every item inside list `a` ranging from `b` to `len(a)`. The result is then concatenated with `a[0:b]` which returns another list, but then you concatenate it with `'ay'` which happens to be a **string** instead of list. Hence, the `TypeError` you've mentioned in the question.

The solution itself might be trivial, just change that specific line and the preceeding if statement into

```py
    if value[i] in vowels:
       b=i
       break
    c=value[b:len(value)]+value[0:b]+'ay'
```

Hope this works!